# Screen rotation on start up

Tags: 15.10, rotate, display-rotation

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my convertible laptop(hp 2760p)
It has a button to turn the screen 90 degrees. I loved that it worked properly, but there is always a little BUT.

I used this button, and now every time I log in, it starts the system turned 90 degrees. It's not a huge problem, but it's annoying
When I was shutting it down the screen was in a normal position.

P.S.: I know I could run a script that would turn it back every time I log in, but I also want to know why is this happening

Comment: If I understand well, it is more a hardware issue than a software issue. Could you test if it happens, logging in with another user on the same system?

Comment: If you like nerdy logs, try looking through /var/log/Xorg.0.log for clues. ...may also want to post it to http://pastebin.com for review.